# INSERT with SELECT SQL statement in Android

Tags: android, sql

I have the following parametrised SQL statement, that I would like to execute in my Android app:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO orders(orderId, orderDate, "
        + "customerId, requiredDate, priceList, taxCode, discount, shipper, "
        + "freight, shipName, ahipAddress, shipCity, shipRegion, shipPostalCode, "
        + "shipCountry, notes, custom) "
        + "SELECT(?, ?, "
        + "customerId, requiredDate, priceList, taxCode, discount, shipper, "
        + "freight, shipName, ahipAddress, shipCity, shipRegion, shipPostalCode, "
        + "shipCountry, notes, custom) " + "FROM orders WHERE _id=?";
```

I also need to know whether the insertion fails due to unique key violation. Is there any way to do this using an SQLiteDatabase object?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Have you actually read the question?

Comment: Yeah I Did. You want to know whether insertion fails. So, I am asking, did you try. If so, what is the error text you are getting?

Comment: Have I quoted any code, apart from the SQL statement? That should give you a clue.